Get list of MFA phone numbers for users
I'm trying to find a way in Powershell to export a list of MFA phone numbers for users. It appears that Graph can do this, but I've not found success.
Per the above article, I tried to use the following commands:
Get-MgUser -All:$true -PipelineVariable user | ForEach-Object {
     Get-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName |
         Select-Object @{ N='UserPrincipalName'; E={ $user.UserPrincipalName }}, ID, PhoneNumber, PhoneType
}

Executing this results in "ForEach-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'UserId' because it is an empty string."
I tried the OP's original commands:
$mgUsers = Get-MgUser -All:$true | Select UserPrincipalName

foreach ($user in $mgUsers) {
    Get-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName | Select ID,PhoneNumber,PhoneType
    }

This did start outputting phone numbers, but no names. There's an Id column, but all of the IDs are the same, so I still have no means of identifying who is who.
I tried the solution in one of the replies (that the OP indicated worked for them), but this also did not provide output. Instead of an error it showed only the Id and UPN data, but the UPN was the same for all of the IDs.
I'm at a loss. I've never used Graph before, and am trying to use this data to true-up some of the data in one of our on-premise databases. If I can get a list of these phone numbers it'll be a lot easier than going through hundreds of users manually in Azure to visually compare their MFA number to the number on record. :/

You need to use the Calculated Property, add  @{ N='UserPrincipalName'; E={ $user.UserPrincipalName }}, before ID. BTW the first code block works fine for me.

I still get errors. Putting the Calculated Property between the Get-MGUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod and before -UserId still tells me that UserID is an empty string.
If I do the same thing using the second script above, I get "Get-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'System.Collections.Hashtable'."

I didn't say UserID I said ID as part of  Select. Read about_Calculated_Properties

Ah, apologies. I still didn't get anything with the first script in my post, but the OP's script worked adding that before the ID portion.
It doesn't seem to let me output to CSV, though--it only winds up writing the last entry to the file.

You need to use a Calculated Property. See about_Calculated_Properties for more details.
$mgUsers = Get-MgUser -All
    
foreach ($user in $mgUsers) {
    Get-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName | Select-Object -Property @{ N='UserPrincipalName'; E={ $user.UserPrincipalName }}, PhoneNumber, PhoneType
}

